# Borrowers that take all loans using NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-division

I want to find the borrowers who took all loan types.

Schema:

```
loan (number (PKEY), type, min_rating)
borrower (cust (PKEY), no (PKEY))
```

Sample tables:

```
number | type     | min_rating
------------------------------
L1     | student  | 500
L2     | car      | 550
L3     | house    | 500
L4     | car      | 700
L5     | car      | 900

cust  | no 
-----------
Jim   | L2
Tom   | L1
Tom   | L2
Tom   | L3
Tom   | L4
Tom   | L5
Bob   | L3
```

The answer here would be "Tom".

I can simply count the total number of loans and compare the borrower's number of loans to that, but I'm NOT allowed to (this is a homework exercise), for the purposes of this homework and learning.

I wanted to use double-negation where I first find the borrowers who didn't take all the loans and find borrowers who are not in that set. I want to use nesting with `NOT EXISTS` where I first find the borrowers that didn't take all the loans but I haven't been able to create a working query for that.

Comment: Think about the problem like this:  There doesn't exist a loan that the borrow doesn't have.

Comment: ... which is *two* `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. But I started off with trying to find the customers that didn't take all the loans using `SELECT b.cust FROM borrower b, loan l WHERE l.no = b.number AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM loan)` and this is incorrect so I was wondering where I should fix it.

Comment: Standard solution to this relational division problem is the double not exists. Look for similar problems and answers  in the "Related" div to the right --->>>

Comment: BTW what is the relevance of the loan.type field? do you want to select all persons with all *types* of loans ?

Comment: @wildplasser I guess they are not that important. The first column is enough.

Comment: As I said: in the *related* div you can find numerous examples of relational division: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17393110/905902

Comment: @wildplasser Yes, thank you, I did look at related posts and it helped me to solve my problem using `NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach is to use the facts:

- that an outer join gives you nulls when there's no join
- coalesce() can turn a null into a blank (that will always be less that a real value)

Thus, the minimum coalesced loan number of a person who doesn't have every loan type will be blank:

```
select cust
from borrower b
left join loan l on l.number = b.no
group by cust
having min(coalesce(l.number, '')) > ''
```

The group-by neatly sidesteps the problem of selecting people more than once (and the ugly subqueries that often requires), and relies on the quite reasonable assumption that a loan number is never blank. Even if that were possible, you could still find a way to make this pattern work (eg coalesce the min_rating to a negative number, etc).

The above query can be re-written, possibly more readably, to use a `NOT IN` expression:

```
select distinct cust
from borrower
where cust not in (
  select cust
  from borrower b
  left join loan l on l.number = b.no
  where l.number is null
)
```

By using the fact that a missed join returns all nulls, the where clause of the inner query keeps only *missed* joins.

You need to use `DISTINCT` to stop borrowers appearing twice.

---

Your schema has a problem - there is a many-to-many relationship between borrower and load, but your schema handles this poorly. `borrower` should have one row for each person, and another *association* table to record the fact that a borrower took out a loan:

```
create table borrower (
    id int,
    name varchar(20)
    -- other columns about the person
);

create table borrrower_loan (
    borrower_id int, -- FK to borrower
    load_number char(2) -- FK to loan
);
```

This would mean you wouldn't need the `distinct` operator (left to you to figure out why), but also handles real life situations like two borrowers having the same name.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with nested queries using NOT IN or NOT EXISTS?

Answer (score 1):

I think a good first step would be to take a cartesian product* of the borrowers and the loans, then use a where clause to filter down to the ones which aren't present in your "borrowers" table.  (Although I think that would use a NOT IN rather than a NOT EXISTS, so may not be exactly what you have in mind?)

(* With the caveat that cartesian products are a terrible thing to do, and you'd need to think very carefully about performance before doing this in real life)

ETA: The NOT EXISTS variant could look like this:
Take the Cartesian product as before, do a correlated subquery for the combination of borrower and loan, then filter by whether this query returns any rows, using a WHERE clause with a NOT EXISTS condition.

Comment: I think both `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` can work but I'm looking for something simple and not too much correlated nesting involved if possible.

Comment: This would have one subquery, and it wouldn't be correlated.  Let me edit in a little more about the NOT EXISTS alternative...

Answer (score 0):

```
select cust from borrower
except
select t.cust
from (select distinct cust,number
      from borrower cross join loan) t
left join borrower b on t.cust = b.cust and t.number = b.num
where b.num is null
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/67a3e/24)

Take a `cross join` of customers from borrowers and loan nums from loans. Then `left join` the `borrower` table to find customers who haven't taken all loans. Finally, use `except` to select the customers who have taken all loans.

Comment: Is there a way you could do it without using joins?

Comment: i will try to come up with an answer without a `join`